# FME - Measure length of line to any point along line

Tags: point, distance, fme-form, linear-referencing

Do you know how can I measure distance from the beginning of line to point. Points are on lines.
I tried some solution and think about measuregenerator, lengthtopointcalculator, neighborfinder... but no success yet.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The [LengthToPointCalculator](https://www.safe.com/transformers/length-to-point-calculator/) will do the task you need:

```
Calculates the length of a feature from its start until the closest spot to a point, and adds it as a new attribute. The point coordinates are taken from attributes in the original feature.
```

For the LengthToPointCalculator, input point coordinates are an attribute of the line feature.  If you have multiple points then the following workflow will:

- input the point features,
- extract each point coordinates to attributes x,y,
- merge point features with the reference line,
- for each, calculate the length along the line using LengthToPointCalculator, and
- return the point features with the length along line as an attribute:
  [image: FME 2017 workbench]
  [Note: tested in FME 2017 x64]